# Using Generics C#

Tags: c#, generics

I'm new to c# and trying to understang generics. I try with this simple class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


    public class Program<T>
    {
        public static void Main()
        {

            List<T> list = new List<T>();

        }
    }
```

But when I run the code, I get the error:

> Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which `ContainsGenericParameters` is true.

What am I missing?

Comment: That code won't even compile. The error you posted is a *reflection* runtime exception which means this code isn't related to the problem.

Comment: A generic `Program`? Why that?

Comment: Why shouldn't it compile? It sure makes no sense, but why would the compiler care?

Comment: @HimBromBeere He's probably just figuring out how generics work. It's quite complicated to pick up

Comment: @ThomasHilbert `Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point`  Main can't be in a generic class.

Comment: @ThomasHilbert You can try to compile the program and see the error for yourself, if you want to know.

Comment: Check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post the actual code that produces the runtime error

Comment: You also cannot create an instance of a generic class without specifying the type. You would need to use List<int> list or something like that.

Comment: @HylianPikachu Type was specified as T.

Comment: @ThomasHilbert not in this code. And that code won't compile in any console application. And the error has nothing to do with that code anyway, it's a reflection exception

Comment: Why not? Ignoring the fact that the compiler won't compile when it cannot find an entrypoint, T is a generic type parameter of class Program, which in turn allows its use as a type argument for other generic types.

Comment: @ThomasHilbert "T" doesn't mean anything until you specify it at instantiation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.containsgenericparameters?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Do you have a type named `T`?  If so, then `List<T> list = new List<T>();` makes some sense (thought naming a type `T` is very confusing).  What are you trying to do?

Comment: See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not make the class which contains your entry point (the `Main()` method) generic (which you did by appending `<T>` to your `Program` class).
But that's not necessary anyway. If you want to use generic classes like `List<T>`, all you have to do is to specify which type you want to use for it's concrete implementation.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<int> list = new List<int>(); // List<T>'s generic parameter T was set to int

        list.Add(5); // 5 is of type int
    }
}
```

This works fine.
You can also build your own generic classes, whose type parameters can in turn be used as arguments for other generic types:

```
class MyGenericClass<A>
{
    public void Example()
    {
        List<A> list = new List<A>(); // List<T>'s generic parameter T was set to whatever A is

        list.Add(default(A)); // default(A) is some default value of type A
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see what you were saying above. You're right; I'm wrong. I got confused.

Comment: So If I understand correctly: you can create a generic class with methods that create and return a List that have to take as a type a generic type of T(imagine that the Example method return that list, is not void); then in the main program you instantiates the method Example by passing a concrete type

Comment: Correct. Assuming the method would be `public static List<A> Example()` and return its `list`, then you could call the method from inside your `Main()` like this `List<string> exampleList = MyGenericClass<string>.Example();`

Answer (score 3):

As people already mentioned in comments your code won't compile, but your question is about basics of generics (List) and I'll try to answer it.

```
List<T>
```

means you need to pass a type parameter to "tell" what type of items your list will contain. So you can type

```
List<string>
```

to create a list of strings. Of course, you can use your own classes, like

```
List<MyClass>
```

to create a list of MyClass objects.